# Do I need a destructor in a derived class that only uses base class private members?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm not a programmer and this code is probably not a nice one (suggestions are well accepted!), I'm trying to write a tool for my analyis and its the first time I'm using templates and polymorphism and here are my implementation:

```
#ifndef XAODREADER_MONOJET_H_
#define XAODREADER_MONOJET_H_
// STL include(s):                                                                                                                                                                                                               
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

// EDM's include(s):                                                                                                                                                                                                             
#include "SUSYTools/SUSYObjDef_xAOD.h"
#include "xAODEgamma/ElectronContainer.h"
#include "xAODMuon/MuonContainer.h"
#include "xAODCore/ShallowCopy.h"
#include "xAODRootAccess/TEvent.h"

template<class T1, class T2>
class MonoJet {

protected:

   std::vector<T1 *> m_particle;
   std::pair<T2 *, xAOD::ShallowAuxContainer *> m_shallow_particle;

public:

   MonoJet(xAOD::TEvent *, const std::string &);
   virtual ~MonoJet();

   std::vector<T1 *> GetParticle();
   void SortByPt();

   virtual void Calibrate(std::shared_ptr<ST::SUSYObjDef_xAOD>
                          SUSYToolObj) = 0;
   virtual void ApplyCuts() = 0;
};

#endif // XAODREADER_MONOJET_H_ 



/////////////////// IMPLEMENTATION



#include <xAODReader/MonoJet.h>

// The constructor:                                                                                                                                                                                                              
template <class T1, class T2>
MonoJet<T1, T2>::MonoJet(xAOD::TEvent *event, const std::string &key)
{
   // Declare the container:                                                                                                                                                                                                     
   const T2 *container = 0;

   // Retrieve Particles:                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   if (!event->retrieve(container, key).isSuccess()) {

      throw std::runtime_error("Failed to retrieve Particle container. Exiting");
   }

   // Make a shallow copy of the container:                                                                                                                                                                                      
   m_shallow_particle = xAOD::shallowCopyContainer(*container);

   // Reserve space to host the particles:                                                                                                                                                                                       
   m_particle.reserve(container->size());

   // Loop over all electrons in the shallow container:                                                                                                                                                                          
   for (auto part_itr : * (m_shallow_particle.first)) {

      m_particle.push_back(part_itr);
   }
}

template<class T1, class T2>
void MonoJet<T1, T2>::SortByPt()
{
   std::sort(std::begin(m_particle), std::end(m_particle),
   [](T1 * e1, T1 * e2) {
      return e1->pt() > e2->pt();
   });
}

template<class T1, class T2>
std::vector<T1 *> MonoJet<T1, T2>::GetParticle()
{
   return m_particle;
}

template <class T1, class T2>
MonoJet<T1, T2>::~MonoJet()
{
   delete m_shallow_particle.first;
   delete m_shallow_particle.second;
}

#include <MonoJetTemplateInstantiations.cxx>
```

and

```
#ifndef XAODREADER_MONOJETELECTRON_H_
#define XAODREADER_MONOJETELECTRON_H_

// STL include(s):                                                                                                                                                                                                               
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>

// EDM's include(s):                                                                                                                                                                                                             
//#include "SUSYTools/SUSYObjDef_xAOD.h"                                                                                                                                                                                         

// Local include(s):                                                                                                                                                                                                             
#include "xAODReader/MonoJetSelectionCuts.h"
#include "xAODReader/MonoJet.h"

class MonoJetElectron : public MonoJet<xAOD::Electron, xAOD::ElectronContainer> {

 public:

  MonoJetElectron(xAOD::TEvent *event, std::string key);
  void Calibrate(std::shared_ptr<ST::SUSYObjDef_xAOD>
                 SUSYToolObj);
  void ApplyCuts();
};

#endif // XAODREADER_MONOJET_H_     


//////////////// IMPLEMENTATION

#include <xAODReader/MonoJetElectron.h>

// Constructor:                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
MonoJetElectron::MonoJetElectron(xAOD::TEvent *event, std::string key) : MonoJet(event, key) {}

// Calibrate the electrons:                                                                                                                                                                                                      
void MonoJetElectron::Calibrate(std::shared_ptr<ST::SUSYObjDef_xAOD> SUSYToolObj)
{
   for (auto el_itr : m_particle) {

      if (!SUSYToolObj->FillElectron(*el_itr, ElectronCuts::ETCUT, ElectronCuts::ETACUT).isSuccess()) {

         throw std::runtime_error("Failed to calibrate the electrons. Exiting");
      }
   }
}

// Apply cuts:                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
void MonoJetElectron::ApplyCuts()
{
   m_particle.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(m_particle), std::end(m_particle),
   [](xAOD::Electron * el) {
      return (el->pt() < ElectronCuts::VETO_PT || std::fabs(el->eta()) > ElectronCuts::VETO_ETA);
   }), std::end(m_particle));
}
```

Then I'm creating the objects like:

```
std::shared_ptr<MonoJet<xAOD::Electron, xAOD::ElectronContainer> >
 el = std::make_shared<MonoJetElectron> (m_event, "ElectronCollection");
```

Do my `destructor` need to be `virtual` in this case? I'm only populating private members of the base class so I think I only need to call its destructor but I would like to know some expert's opinion!

Answer (score 3):

You should use virtual destructor in class `MonoJet` as you are using this as base class and for enforcing polymorphism. When the pointer of `MonoJet` holding a reference to `MonoJetElectron` is deleted then behavior is undefined. This is a safe practice to avoid memory leaks and proper cleanup of objects in class hierarchy.

You don't need to use virtual destructor in class `MonoJetElectron` unless you have any virtual methods in this class or intend to use it as a base class. And if `MonoJet` has a virtual destructor then also you don't need to explicitly declare the `MonoJetElectron` destructor virtual. It will be implicitly virtual as per standard.

For more reference you can refer below link: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors

Comment: Shall I implement a destructor for MonoJetElectron as well? Should it look like the one in the base class?

Comment: I am fairly sure deleting a `MonoJet` referring to a `MonoJetElectron` with `MonoJet::~MonoJet` not being `virtual` is not undefined behavior.

Comment: @nwp The behavior is undefined in that case. You might want to refer to C++11 standard draft doc (https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3690.pdf) also. Section 5.3.5 Pt. 3

Comment: @drkg4b : If you have virtual destructor in base class then you don't need to declare the destructor of derived class virtual. It will be implicitly virtual even if it's user defined.  For more reference: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/virtual-dtors.html